# Polymer slide-up-animation: how to make it start from the bottom of the page?

Tags: javascript, animation, polymer-1.0

Using Polymer 1.1 I am trying to use `slide-up-animation`. The issue I have is that when it slides up, it starts from the middle of the page rather from the bottom and sliding up.

Although it's not in the docs, this code example https://github.com/PolymerElements/neon-animation/blob/master/demo/dropdown/animated-dropdown.html shows I can use `transformOrigin`. However, it's not working for me. I don't know if it's because I am using neon animation pages or not. Any ideas on how to make it slide up from the bottom of the page?

```
    <neon-animated-pages selected="[[selected]]"
    >
      <portfolio-page></portfolio-page>
```

```
 <script>
    Polymer({
      is: "portfolio-page",
      behaviors: [Polymer.NeonAnimatableBehavior,
                  Polymer.NeonAnimationRunnerBehavior],
      properties: {
        animationConfig: {
          type: Object,
          value: function() {
            return {
              'entry': {
                name: 'slide-up-animation',
                node: this,
                transformOrigin: 'bottom'
              },
              'exit': {
                name: 'slide-up-animation',
                node: this,
                transformOrigin: 'bottom'
              }
            }
          }
        },
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use slide-up, you have to create a different animation:

```
<script>

  Polymer({

    is: 'slide-from-bottom-animation',

    behaviors: [
      Polymer.NeonAnimationBehavior
    ],

    configure: function(config) {
      var node = config.node;

      if (config.transformOrigin) {
        this.setPrefixedProperty(node, 'transformOrigin', config.transformOrigin);
      } else {
        this.setPrefixedProperty(node, 'transformOrigin', '50% 0');
      }

      this._effect = new KeyframeEffect(node, [
        {'transform': 'translateY(100%)'},
        {'transform': 'none'}
      ], this.timingFromConfig(config));

      return this._effect;
    }

  });

</script>
```

Comment: Thanks. Can you please explain why I can't use slide up and the `transformOrigin`? I saw it in the sourcecode as an option, even though it wouldn't work.

Comment: My understanding is that the original effect starts from translateY:0, and goes to translateY:-100%, which causes top of the element to slide out of view. It does not matter where the origin is, it'll always slide the top to -100%. What my animation does is different, sliding from 100% to 0.

Answer (score 0):

Or if you don't wan't to create your own animation you can use `transform-animation`.

```
return {
 'entry': {
    name: 'transform-animation',
    transformFrom: 'translateY(100%)',
    transformTo: 'none',
    node: this,
    timing: {duration: 2000},
},
```